# HTTPS requests over open proxy servers

Tags: proxy, https, security, tunnel

*I will keep this simple.*
It's possible, or there is a special type of proxy for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible. The host (address/port) you're doing the request to isn't encrypted, and the proxy server just forwards the bytes you're sending (encrypted or not), and of course gives you the response.

Answer (score 2):

If not exposing your clients IP address to the Server is important you should understand that you'll need to have the proxy actually make the HTTPS request.  Otherwise, it will look as such:

```
Client -+- [CONNECT] ---> Proxy --- [DIRECT TCP] -+-> Server  
   |                       |                              |        
   +---------------[ENCRYPTED TCP]------------------------+
```

What you may want is this:

```
Client -+- [DIRECT TCP] ---> Proxy --- [CONNECT] -+-> Server  
                              |                         |        
                              +-------------------------+
```

I have yet to find a library that works well for this second method.